# php mysql server execution time - want to reset after every time a function is called. is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, function, execution-time

I'm using a recursive function to do some calculation for every user and reward them for certain condition. Everything was working fine, but now that my user number has increased to something like 20000+ my script cannot be completed... my code is like

```
function give_award($mid) {

    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$mid'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array_result)
     {
      $refer = $row["refer"];
     }
    //some conditions applied
    //query for user award
    //if succeed

    $mid = $mid+1;
    give_award($mid)


}

give_award($mid);
```

I'm Sure give_award(); isn't doing the time out in a single time calling. Is there a way that I can reset the time limit every time before the function is recursively (re)called?

Ways I've tried:
set_time_limit(0);

changing the timeout limit in .htaccess
changing apache timeout limit in php.ini

NB: No fatal error was show... But I've to restart apache every time I try to run this on local server... Using Zend Server Community edition on Win7 32bit.

Please help

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using recursion ?

Comment: On a side note, what _is_ PHP's recurse limit? I seem to remember I hit it some time ago with some coding error. And Gianluca is right: you should just loop through the users, not recurse like this.

Comment: Thanks Gianluca and Wrikken. You're right that I should use loops not recursive functions. But then again, should I just loop the function for all users? or should I create a loop not a function? When I run the function with a loop, it generates the same old problem...

Comment: Also, whats the best method for this kind of execution? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to find the recursion limit, but this is not a place to use it as far as I can tell anyway. A quick test here:

```
<?php
function KillingRecurse($r){
        echo $r.PHP_EOL;
        KillingRecurse(++$r);
}
KillingRecurse(0);
```

Result:

```
...
20916
Segmentation fault
```

I'm not surprised a segfault causes the server to need to be restarted, and the numbers kind of match up.

Tell us more about what you are trying to do here, because *recursing* through all users seems maddness here...

Comment: What I'm trying to do : I have a system with more than 20000 users. They have certain left and right referral values. I need to compare those with a condition and give them incentives based on it. Like if a user has 40 person in his left and 40 person in his right, I need to give him an incentive of $2 equivalent.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what your data looks like. Post the relevant CREATE TABLE statements, and explain in detail what it is that must be done.